# How to update custom taxonomy meta using ACF update_field() function or any other wordpress function

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update the Advanced Custom Fields meta value associated with a custom taxonomy term

```
$term_status = wp_update_term( $rate_id, 'rate', $term_data );

$term_id = $term_status['term_taxonomy_id'];

update_field( 'field_56829855eebc9',$rate_daily,$term_id );
```

However, I'm not getting the field updated. I have tried the field name instead of the field key too.

Comment: Questions regarding 3rd Party Plugins ( such as Advanced Custom Fields ) are considered to be [Off-Topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). ACF has [their own support](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out somehow..

Syntax of `update_field()`:

`update_field($field_key, $value, $post_id)`

MY MISTAKE:
I was using the wrong parameter for the `$post_id` which i thought was the Term Id of the custom taxonomy term.

CORRECT USAGE: rather than using term id (`$term_id` in my question), one should use a string with the taxonomy preppended to the $term_id

ie `$post_id` = `$taxonomy.'_'.$term_id`

for eg: if your custom taxonomy is `foo` and the term id is `123`

then : `$post_id = foo_123`

Hope this is helpful for someone.

This is the first time I'm asking/answering a question here.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just want to point out a typo as well. You forgot the underscore: it's `$term_name . '_' . $term_id`

Comment: note: this should be the name of the taxonomy followed by the term id

Comment: @eballeste thank you for this. Iwas having the same issue, landing me on this post, and you caused me to slow down and review all the pieces of my issue ... only to find that I had incorrectly typed the name of my own custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me:

```
update_term_meta($term_id, $field['name'], $value);
```

In my case i have an "author" taxonomy with a custom field called "institution", so i did:

```
$my_author_taxonomy = get_term_by( "name", $author_taxonomy_name, 'author' );   
update_term_meta($my_author_taxonomy->term_id, "institution", $Institution);
```

I hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I had success using [wp_set_object_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/), as suggested by the [official ACF support](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/update_field-for-taxonomy-field-type/).