# Gravity Forms with Advanced Post Creation Add-On not updating ACF fields on custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-gravity-forms

I've tried everything I can think of and read about. I cannot seem to figure out why this doesn't work, let alone get it to work. I have a Custom post type called Talk. That custom post type has a custom taxonomy (non-hierarchical) of Speaker. The taxonomy Speaker has three Advanced Custom Fields added to it: Institution, Phone, Email.

A Gravity Form using the Advanced Post Creation add-on creates a Talk as a draft. The speaker name, institution, phone and email are all fields on that form. Below is the latest version of my attempts to have the Speaker ACF update after post creation.

```
add_action( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation_2', 'after_post_creation', 10, 4 );
function after_post_creation( $post_id, $feed, $entry, $form ){
    $spkr_inst = rgar( $entry, '3' );
    $spkr_ph = rgar( $entry, '10' );
    $spkr_em = rgar( $entry, '11' );
    $talk_speakers = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'talk_speaker' );
    foreach($talk_speakers as $talk_speaker) {
        $spkr_id = 'speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id;
        GFCommon::send_email( 'a@b.com', 'a@b.com','','','New Post', $spkr_id);
        // update_field( 'speaker_institution', $spkr_inst, 'speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id);
        // update_field( 'speaker_phone_number', $spkr_ph, 'speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id);
        // update_field( 'speaker_email_address', $spkr_em, 'speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id);
    }
}
```

The commented out update_field stuff NEVER happens, whether I'm using `'speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id` or the above `$spkr_id`.
But the test email sends, and has the correct $spkr_id value in the email body,  speaker_112 ...

I've read through these (but far be it from me to assume I missed nothing ...):

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#update-a-value-from-different-objects

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation/#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Thanks to this question: [How to update custom taxonomy meta using ACF update_field() function or any other wordpress function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213354/how-to-update-custom-taxonomy-meta-using-acf-update-field-function-or-any-othe)

I slowed down long enough to realize I typed the function name of my own dang custom taxonomy incorrectly when prefixing the term id ... should have been `'talk_speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id;` not just `speaker_` ... in short, what I have works, if I didn't make that mistake.

Good night sleep and some coffee will do wonders.

Final Code:

```
add_action( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation_2', 'after_post_creation', 10, 4 );
function after_post_creation( $post_id, $feed, $entry, $form ){
    $spkr_inst = rgar( $entry, '3' );
    $spkr_ph = rgar( $entry, '10' );
    $spkr_em = rgar( $entry, '11' );
    $talk_speakers = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'talk_speaker' );
    foreach($talk_speakers as $talk_speaker) {
        $spkr_id = 'talk_speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id;
        update_field( 'speaker_institution', $spkr_inst, $spkr_id);
        update_field( 'speaker_phone_number', $spkr_ph, $spkr_id);
        update_field( 'speaker_email_address', $spkr_em, $spkr_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue with Gravity Forms and the Advanced Post Creation Add-On not updating ACF fields on a custom taxonomy, you can try adding the following code snippet to your WordPress theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'gform_post_create_post', 'update_custom_taxonomy_acf_fields', 10, 3 );
function update_custom_taxonomy_acf_fields( $post_id, $form, $entry ) {
    // Check if the custom taxonomy term is set in the Gravity Form entry
    $custom_taxonomy_term = rgar( $entry, 'custom_taxonomy_field_id' );
    if ( ! $custom_taxonomy_term ) {
        return;
    }

    // Update the custom taxonomy term for the post
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $custom_taxonomy_term, 'custom_taxonomy', false );

    // Update the ACF field for the custom taxonomy term
    update_field( 'acf_field_name', $custom_taxonomy_term, $post_id );
}
```

In this example, the code uses the gform_post_create_post action to hook into the Advanced Post Creation Add-On and update the custom taxonomy term and ACF field when a post is created. The code first checks if the custom taxonomy term is set in the Gravity Form entry, and if it is, it uses the wp_set_object_terms() function to update the custom taxonomy term for the post and the update_field() function from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to update the ACF field.

Note: Make sure to replace "custom_taxonomy_field_id" with the actual field ID for the custom taxonomy field in your Gravity Form, "custom_taxonomy" with the actual name of your custom taxonomy, and "acf_field_name" with the actual name of your ACF field.

Comment: Thank you for weighing in. One piece of your code to note is the $post_id ... the value available upon GF form submission is not the value needed for the ACF update_field function. You would need to use taxonomy_function_name_N (where N is the term_id) in order to get the update to the ACF on the taxonomy term. See here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#update-a-value-from-different-objects

In my code that's $spkr_id = 'talk_speaker_'.$talk_speaker->term_id; which I originally (and foolishly) prefixed with 'speaker_' ... once I realized this, it was quick work.